# Setting session timeout in RedisSessionStateProvider 1.6

Tags: asp.net, caching, azure, session-state

I'm using RedisSessionStateProvider 1.6 and the following configuration:

```
<sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="AzureRedisCacheSessionState" timeout="10">
  <providers>
    <add name="AzureRedisCacheSessionState" type="Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider" ... />
  </providers>
</sessionState>
```

But the 'timeout' value doesn't seem to work - whatever I put it just seems to use the default value of 20 minutes.

The session times out in 20 minutes (sliding), and Session.Timeout always returns 20.

This problem seems to be specific to version 1.6 - I tried installing version 1.5 instead and that works correctly.

I'm aware that there were some issues with the timeout being treated as absolute instead of sliding a couple of versions ago (I believe this bug was introduced in version 1.4 and fixed in version 1.5) - the issue I'm having is NOT the same.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and after I rebuild web, restarted IIS and restarted my redis server - it took in account the setting in the timeout="123".